# How can we reshape Python Pandas DataFrame to C-Contiguous memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am loading a two dimensional dataset in memory with Pandas, and doing 4 simple Machine Learning pre-processing task like adding/removing columns, reindexing, train/test split.

```
#Read file
MLMe = pd.read_table("data/dtCTG.txt", ",")
#Label target column to "class"
MLMe.rename(columns={'NSP' : 'class'}, inplace=True)

#Create train/test indices
MLMe_class = MLMe['class'].values
training_indices, validation_indices = training_indices, testing_indices = train_test_split(
MLMe.index, stratify = MLMe_class, train_size=0.75, test_size=0.25)

#Create train/test data sets
X_train = MLMe.drop('class',axis=1).loc[training_indices].values
y_train = MLMe.loc[training_indices,'class'].values

X_test = MLMe.drop('class',axis=1).loc[validation_indices].values
y_test = MLMe.loc[validation_indices, 'class'].values

#Final datasets to be used for training
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test
```

Now when I pass X_train, y_train dataframes to some libraries, I get an error message that buffers are no longer C-contiguous.

```
BufferError: memoryview: underlying buffer is not C-contiguous
```

**My question is:** *How can I make X_train, y_train C-contiguous buffers?*  I tried reshaping with C and F options, but no luck.

EDIT: Here are the shape, dtypes, and flags for the dataframes:

```
X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape
((1104, 9), (1104,), (369, 9), (369,))
X_train.dtype, y_train.dtype, X_test.dtype, y_test.dtype
(dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'))
X_train.flags, y_train.flags, X_test.flags, y_test.flags
(  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
   F_CONTIGUOUS : True
   OWNDATA : False
   WRITEABLE : True
   ALIGNED : True
   UPDATEIFCOPY : False,   

   C_CONTIGUOUS : True
   F_CONTIGUOUS : True
   OWNDATA : True
   WRITEABLE : True
   ALIGNED : True
   UPDATEIFCOPY : False,   

   C_CONTIGUOUS : False
   F_CONTIGUOUS : True
   OWNDATA : False
   WRITEABLE : True
   ALIGNED : True
   UPDATEIFCOPY : False,   

   C_CONTIGUOUS : True
   F_CONTIGUOUS : True
   OWNDATA : True
   WRITEABLE : True
   ALIGNED : True
   UPDATEIFCOPY : False
)
```

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/2960) and [this](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/pull/3513)- you may find some useful information there...

Comment: Show us the dtype, shape, FLAGS of the arrays in question.

Comment: Have you tried `X_train=np.ascontiguousarray(X_train)` ?

Comment: I added the dtype, shape, FLAGS info for the datasets.  Two are not C_Contiguous: I guess the solution is to make them C_Contiguous, but not sure how.

Comment: @Happy001 Wow, your solution did the trick!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We have no direct control about how the DataFrame stores its values, which can be c-contiguous or not. However, it's easy to get C-contiguous data by using the numpy function `ascontiguousarray` on the underlying numpy array, which is returned by the `value` property of the array. You can test it for yourself:

```
X_train.flags.c_contiguous  # Checks if the array is C-contiguous
#>>> False
X_train = np.ascontiguousarray(X_train) # Converts the array to C-contiguous
X_train.flags.c_contiguous
#>>> True
```

The documentation for `numpy.ascontiguousarray` the can be found here:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html